# Why some Java classes' constructor be shown as private without private keyword?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have encountered a weird situation today for second time which keeps my mind busy. The problem has started when i looked Matcher class's constructors which are not declared as private. I thought, i can invoke Matcher's constructor in other class with creating object of it. But my IDE has shown the constructors as private.
[Constructors of Matcher class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnBOM.png)

And i am wondering why cannot i access those constructors? The second time was in Bitmap class from Android Library. I haven't worked with Matcher or any related class. This is the first time, i am dealing with it. I would be grateful if you guys and ladies can help. Thanks in advance. BTW, I am using IntelliJ Idea as IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are package protected. So you can call those only in classes in the same package.

Comment: Or or from a derived class.

Comment: Yes, my answer is based on the image of `class Matcher` linked in question but it can be also derived.

Comment: @Arkadiy No, only from the same package.

Comment: Oh my, not sure where I've got this misconception. You're right, package classes only, no subclass.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. And i will be more careful next time before asking a question which has answer in Stack Overflow.